# How to add text above plot centered by plot ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I would like to add the texts above plot which will be centered between two ticks. I've prepared the code which reminds the image at the end of this question. How can I add texts *Forming*, *Storming*, etc. exactly like on the image?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] at (1.425,3.5) {\scriptsize{Pracująca grupa}};
    \node[] at (4.325,1.5) {\scriptsize{Pseudo zespół}};
    \node[] at (7.225,5.75) {\scriptsize{Potencjalny zespół}};
    \node[] at (10.0955,4.5) {\scriptsize{Prawdziwy zespół}};
    \node[] at (12.975,5) {\scriptsize{Wydajny zespół}};
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none,
    axis lines=left,
    title={\textbf{Fazy Tuckman'a}},
    xlabel={Skuteczność zespołu},
    ylabel={Wpływ na wydajność zespołu},
    width=160mm,
    height=90mm,
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    smooth,
    color=black
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,33.75)(6.5,40)(20,18.75)(30,10)(40,18.75)(60,68.75)(80,80)(90,78)(100,78)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: Stages of group development - Tuckman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `extra x ticks` in the `axis` options:

```
extra x ticks={10,30,...,90},
extra x tick style={grid=none,ticks=major,ticklabel pos=right},
extra x tick labels={Forming,Storming,Norming, Performing,Adjourning},
title style={yshift={20pt}},
xlabel style={at=(xticklabel* cs:0.5)}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ticks=none,
  axis lines=left,
  title={\textbf{Fazy Tuckman'a}},
  xlabel={Skuteczność zespołu},
  ylabel={Wpływ na wydajność zespołu},
  width=160mm,
  height=90mm,
  xmin=0, xmax=100,
  ymin=0, ymax=100,
  xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
  xmajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
  extra x ticks={10,30,...,90},
  extra x tick style={grid=none,ticks=major,ticklabel pos=right},
  extra x tick labels={Forming,Storming,Norming, Performing,Adjourning},
  title style={yshift={20pt}},
  xlabel style={at=(xticklabel* cs:0.5)}
]

\addplot[
  smooth,
  color=black
  ]
  coordinates {
  (0,33.75)(6.5,40)(20,18.75)(30,10)(40,18.75)(60,68.75)(80,80)(90,78)(100,78)
  };
\path[nodes={font=\scriptsize}]
  (10,47) node {Pracująca grupa}
  (30,20) node {Pseudo zespół}
  (50,75) node {Potencjalny zespół}
  (70,60) node {Prawdziwy zespół}
  (90,65) node {Wydajny zespół}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```